# Redirigir formulario a nueva página evitando errores

Tags: php, html

Necesito que salga por el if y me lleve a la página de *gracias.php* y no salga por el `else`. No encuentro el error.

```
  //Obtenemos variables y validamos

  $nombre = $empresa = $email = $servicio = $telefono = $comentario = $comment = $privacidad = $mensajeAdmin = $priv = false;

  require("_lib/PHPMailer.php");
  // require("_lib/SMTP.php"); //En caso de usar SMTP
  // require("_lib/Exception.php");

  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  // use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP; //En caso de usar SMTP
  // use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth; //En caso de usar SMTP
  // use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google; //En caso de usar SMTP
    
  //Obtenemos variables y validamos
  
  function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }

    if($arrResponse["success"] == '1' && $arrResponse["score"] >= 0.5) {

  $nombre = test_input($_POST["nombre"]);
  $empresa = test_input($_POST["empresa"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $servicio = test_input($_POST["servicio"]);
  $telefono = test_input($_POST["telefono"]);
  $comentario = test_input($_POST["comentarios"]);
  $privacidad = intval($_POST['privacidad']);

  if($privacidad != 1){
    $priv = 'NO Acepta la política de privacidad';
  } else {
    $priv = 'Acepta la política de privacidad';
  }

  $comment = $comentario != '' ? '<p><strong>Mensaje: </strong>'.$comentario.'</p>' : '';

  /* MENSAJE PARA EMPRESA */
  $mensajeAdmin = '<h2>Nuevo formulario de contacto</h2>
                  <hr>
                  <h3>Datos del solicitante:</h3>
                  <p><strong>Nombre: </strong>'.$nombre.'</p>
                  <p><strong>Empresa: </strong>'.$empresa.'</p>
                  <p><strong>Email: </strong>'.$email.'</p>
                  <p><strong>Teléfono: </strong>'.$telefono.'</p>'
                  .$comment.
                  '<p><strong>URL o Servicio: </strong>'.$servicio.'</p>
                  <hr>
                  <p><strong>Privacidad: </strong>'.$priv.'</p>';

  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

  $mail = new PHPMailer;

  $mail->From = "noreply@prueba.es"; //Email sender
  $mail->FromName = "Formulario Herbusa"; //Nombre sender

  $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                
  $mail->IsHTML(true);                                 
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

  $mail->AddAddress('prueba@pruebaes'); //Email destinatario
  // $mail->addBCC('prueba@prueba.com'); //Email en copia oculta
  // $mail->addBCC('prueba@prueba.com'); //Email en copia oculta
  
  $mail->Subject = 'Nuevo formulario | prueba'; //Asunto
  $mail->Body    = $mensajeAdmin;
  
  $mail->send();

  header('Location: gracias.php');
  
} else {
  echo 'Ha ocurrido un error, por favor, vuelva a intentarlo';
}

}
```

Comment: Si no entra en un if es que no cumple la comparacion, comprueba que te da $arrResponse["success"]  $arrResponse["score"] en el caso de que sea un formulario correcto

Comment: No estas recogiendo la variable $arrResponse en ningún momento , revisa que no este vacia.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a estructurar bien los if ya que el codigo posterior al siguiente if parece que esta mal tabulado:
`if($arrResponse["success"] == '1' && $arrResponse["score"] >= 0.5)`
Además, intenta printear la variable `$arrResponse` ya que no la estas recogiendo y printeandola veras que no tiene ningun valor en su interior. Una vez le asignes el valor correspondiente debería de funcionar el if.